# POST form data using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, rest, post

I'm trying to use AngularJS to POST a form to an API I'm developing.

The form has `novalidate`, `name="addMatchForm"`, and `ng-submit="submit(addMatchForm)"`. The `addMatchForm` is as followed:

```
app.controller('addMatchController', ['$scope', 'players', 'matches', function($scope, players, matches) {

    ...

    $scope.submit = function(form) {
        form.submitted = true;

        // Make sure we don't submit the form if it's invalid
        if ( form.$invalid ) return;

        matches.add(form).success(function(data) {
            console.log('post result:', data);
        })
    }
}]);

app.factory('matches', function($http) {
    return {
        add: function(data) {
            return $http.post('/matches', data);
        }
    }
});
```

But the weird thing is that each and every input's value becomes an empty object at that point. This is the Form Data from Chrome Developer Tools:

```
{"a_score":{},"b_score":{},"day":{},"month":{},"year":{},"a_player1":{},"a_player2":{},"b_player1":{},"b_player2":{},"submitted":true}:
```

I did add the `content-type` part already.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What point the values become empty?

Comment: I guess after the `post`. It still is the object when I do `console.log(data)` before the `return $http.post(...);`.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use $http like this:

```
return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/matches',
    data: $.param(data),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});
```

Comment: When I replaced my `$http` with the one you provided I got the following error: ` Cannot read property '$name' of undefined`. Any ideas on where this might come from? Might it be the fact that I'm also including jQuery?

Comment: @CasCornelissen try to click on the error. it should jump to the line where it happens.

Comment: Took some time (I switched to the unminified angular.js), but it's in the middel of `function consoleLog(type)`, at `return logFn.apply(console, args);` to be exact.

Comment: It looks like it's the `$.params`, when I use `data: data` instead I don't get the error. The problem with empty objects still exists, though :(

Comment: @CasCornelissen do you want to post the data in json format or as from url encoded? $.param is a jquery function which encodes javascript objects/arrays to query string format

Comment: I want it to be url encoded, hence the `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";` in my original post.

Comment: All right, I figured it out. I passed the whole form object (including stuff like `$dirty`, `$valid`, etc.). I created a new object in the controller that contains all fields and those get updated via the two-way data binding. I ended up using the `$http` method you suggested, though!